# How to get table names with just 1 column in their primary key collection

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database. As you know, some tables may have primary key with either 1 column, such as:

```
`table1` PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
```

OR multiple columns, such as:

```
`table2` PRIMARY KEY(`id`,`pattern_id`)
```

How to get tables that have only 1 column in their primary key? e.g. `table1`

Answer (score 0):

You can select the table names that have only 1 row defined as primary key:

```
    SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '<you_db_name>')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') and TABLE_NAME not in 
  (SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = '<you_db_name>')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI') group by TABLE_NAME having COUNT(TABLE_NAME)>1)
```